# g++ throws Skeleton wxwidget project "undefined reference to main" errors

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

Target Platform  : Linux mint 9 (Ubuntu Lucid Distribution)
Compiler         : g++ 4.4.3
wxwidget         : 2.8

Project Title    : BareBones
Files            : BareBonesApp.cpp , BareBonesApp.rc  , BareBonesFrm.h
                   BareBonesApp.h   , BareBonesFrm.cpp , BareBonesFrm.wxform

IDE              : Nil (Made the project in wxdevcpp in windows mingw
                   successfully compiles and executes the barebones app)
Editor           : Gedit 
Compiler Output & Files link  : http://pastebin.com/eTMtDw9h
Observation      :Something to do with `IMPLEMENT_APP(BareBonesFrmApp)`
Experience       :Newbie
Goal             :Need a solution for g++ to successfully compile BareBonesFrm.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding BareBonesApp.cpp:

```
g++ BareBonesFrm.cpp BareBonesApp.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags` `wx-config --libs` -o BareBones
```

Comment: You can combine that to `wx-config --cxxflags --libs`.

Comment: @user502515 for that to work, you have to do something like `wx-config --libs --cxxflags | tr [:space:] ' '` otherwise GCC still produces the same linker errors. ffs I didn't even have to think about the commands when I compiled this with clang; it just compiled

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile all cpp files of the project not only BareBonesFrm.cpp, then it might be able to find its main in the IMPLEMENT_APP macro (defined in BareBonesApp, which are not compiled.)